# Rails simple_form, bootstrap-datepicker gem issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have the following simple_form input that I want to behave as a datepicker (using bootstrap-datepicker gem):

```
<%= f.input :install_date, :as => 'string', input_html: {data: {behavior: "datepicker"}} %>
```

I have the following in my application.js file:

```
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

I have the following in my application.css file:

```
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker3
```

I have the following code in my jobs.js.coffee file to trigger the datepicker:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

I am able to make this work using standard html/css and calling the function on the html input, but using the simple_form syntax I am having no luck finding the right code to make this work.

I have read through a litany of SO questions for similar issues, but for older gem versions etc and the syntax doesn't seem to work anymore.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Seems like you need to add class `datepicker` to that input element to make it work.

Comment: @Bongs any idea how to properly write that syntax in?  I have it as input_html: {class: "datepicker", data: {behavior: "datepicker"}} and I'm not getting anything different.

Comment: I'm not really sure but try writing it as `:input_html => {:class => "datepicker", "data-behavior" => "datepicker"}`.